# TRIGGER FUNCTION Grade Check PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I created a scholarship database with and apply table

```
 applyid |  studid   |    gpa    | other |  sch_id  |    date    | sem | sy
---------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+-----+----
       1 | 2010-0000 | 1.5       |       |        1 |            |     |
       2 | 2010-0001 | 1.5       |       |        7 | 2014-03-13 |     |
       3 | 2010-0003 |           |       |        1 | 2014-03-13 |     |
       4 | 2010-0003 |           |       |        1 | 2014-03-13 |     |
       5 | 2010-0003 |           |       |        1 | 2014-03-13 |     |
    2308 | 2012-0004 | 1.5       |       |        1 | 2014-03-19 |     |
    4593 | 2012-0004 | 1.5       |       |        1 | 2014-03-19 |     |
    4596 | 2012-0004 | 1.5       |       |        1 | 2014-03-19 |     |
    4597 | 2012-0004 | 1.5       |       |        1 | 2014-03-19 |     |
(9 rows)
```

and currently working on this trigger function that checks if a particular student has either a grade of INC, DRP, 5.00.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fail_check() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
one RECORD;
two RECORD;

BEGIN

   SELECT * INTO one FROM grade, registration;

   IF (SELECT COUNT(g.grade)::int  
       FROM grade g
         INNER JOIN registration r ON r.grade_id = g.grade_id
       WHERE g.grade IN ('INC', 'DRP', '5.00')
     AND studid=new.studid) <= 1 
   THEN 
    SELECT studid, gpa, sch_name INTO two
        FROM apply WHERE studid=new.studid;

    INSERT INTO apply(studid, gpa, sch_name)
    VALUES (new.studid, new.gpa, new.sch_name);

   END IF;

  RETURN NEW;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER fail
BEFORE INSERT ON apply
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fail_check();
```

but when I entered this:

```
INSERT INTO apply(studid, gpa, sch_name) 
VALUES ('2012-0004', '1.5', 1);
```

The student with the student id of "2012-0004" has a grade of INC DRP and 5.00. the `SELECT` query works perfectly fine and returns the value 3. Since 3 is greater than 1, which is contrary to the `IF` statement that says `IF .... <= 1`, I'm expecting an error that says something like that it can't be inserted because the "student" has more than 1 grade of either INC, DRP, 5.00.

But instead I got this error:

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded 
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate. 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(g.grade) 
       FROM grade g
         INNER JOIN registration r ON r.grade_id = g.grade_id
       WHERE g.grade IN ('INC', 'DRP', '5.00')   AND studid=new.studid) <= 1" PL/pgSQL function fail_check() line 12 at IF SQL statement "INSERT INTO apply(studid, gpa, sch_name)  VALUES (new.studid, new.gpa, new.sch_name)" PL/pgSQL function fail_check() line 21 at SQL statement SQL statement "INSERT INTO apply(studid, gpa, sch_name)     VALUES (new.studid, new.gpa, new.sch_name)"
```

Where did I go wrong?? and what does this max_stack_depth exactly mean?? Which part of my code caused this max_stack_depth error??

Currently using PostgreSQL 9.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger `BEFORE INSERT` triggers more INSERTs to the same table, which causes an endless loop. Hence the stack overflow. You seem to be under the impression that you need this in your trigger:

```
INSERT INTO apply(studid, gpa, sch_name)   
VALUES (new.studid, new.gpa, new.sch_name);
```

But you don't. `RETURN NEW;` is enough to let the original INSERT go through.

The rest of your trigger doesn't seem to do anything useful, but that's probably just a simplification.

Comment: Oh It works now. I kind of changed everything and removed the `INSERT` and you're right, the trigger I posted didnt really do anything useful. Thanks!